# debugging (byebug), a time error occurs without returning a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

debugging (byebug), a time error occurs without returning a value.

### environment

rails 6
vue
docker(docker-compose)

### overview

I'm trying to debug by embedding byebug.
processing is stopped at the embedded part of byebug,
Even if I type the value I want to debug there, nothing is returned,It will be a time error of nginx as it is.
[image]

[image]

### I tried

docker-compose up -d
↓
docker ps
↓
docker attach 319f93370244
↓
Put byebug in the place where you want to stop the process and move the corresponding process
↓
Processing stopped and (byebug) is displayed on the attached screen
↓
No response when I type in the value I want to debug

Answer (score 0):

I installed [pry-byebug] and replaced it with [binding.pry]